# can't get an asp:RegularExpressionValidator to work

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having an issue getting a regex field validator to work for an asp page i'm trying to update.

Here is the asp:Panel stripped down to the important bits:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlEmailAddressCollection" runat="server">
    <div id="POMInput-wrapper">
        <div class="POMInput-FieldText">
            <span class="POMInput-wrapper-text">Name:</span>

            <br />
            <span class="POMInput-wrapper-text">Email Address:</span>

            <br />
        </div>
        <div class="POMInput-FieldEntry">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailAddress" name="emailAddress" runat="server" CssClass="textInput"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" name="firstName" CssClass="textInput"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvNameValidator"  runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="Please enter your name"
            ControlToValidate="txtUserName" 
            Display="None" />

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="Please enter your email address"
            ControlToValidate="txtEmailAddress" 
            Display="None" />

        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rfvEmailValidator2" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid email address" 
            ControlToValidate="txtEmailAddress"
            Display="None"
            ValidationExpression="^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$" />

        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server"
            ShowMessageBox="true" 
            ShowSummary="false"
            EnableClientScript="true" />                        
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

It is currently failing on any email i put in. The asp:RequiredFieldValidator's work as expected.

I tested the regular expression in a test project and the regex seems good (returns true on valid emails, false on invalid ones). Did I set up the asp:RegularExpressionValidator incorrectly?

Comment: does the other validations work?

Comment: yes, the RequiredFieldValidators work as advertised.

Comment: Have you tried temporarily using a simpler, trivial regex that will always pass? You need to figure out if it is your expression or the wiring of the validators.

Comment: try this regex **\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)***.

Comment: @n8wrl good call - ".*" passes validation. i guess it doesn't like part of the expression. do you need to url encode the expression?

Comment: ok, looking at the docs, it says that a 'jscript regular expression' syntax is used... i'll have to see if something in my expression above doesn't fit that syntax.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan I see that regex come up in a couple google searches - but it fails on 'test@test.com', which is obviously a valid email address.

Comment: @MikeCorcoran, this regex is given by RegularExpressionValidator control itself. In the property of validation expression you can see this expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove double backslash:

```
ValidationExpression="^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$"
```

Note that you put two backslashes where you meant only one. If you were to set this expression from code behind, the string you provided is correct. But in aspx you don't have to escape backslash.

At the moment accepted email address would be something like abc@abc{backslash}.com

Comment: this doesn't work either. i'm wondering if there is something else in my markup somewhere screwing this up...

Comment: I copy-pasted your validator markup to my project, wired it to first random textbox control and everything worked as intended by you (with my correction to double-backslash issue mentioned above). So if you say other validators work for you, there is something fishy out there :)

Comment: i ended up just switching this to standard form fields and javascript validation. there's too much other markup in the page to try to whittle down where the issue was - i may revisit it at some point. it was some legacy page from a previous developer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
ValidationExpression="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
```

Nota : you can delete  ^ and $ symbols

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression works within .NET (server-side), but is failing due to the client-side JScript implemetation as [documented in the **Remarks** section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx). To verify this (it passes server-side validation), set the `EnableClientScript` property on the validator to false.

Then undo that change and verify the regex will pass on the client side. You can use an [online tester](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html), if it's easier for you.